# How do I hide the default settings while editing settings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to open my default settings, I always see the default settings on the left hand-side. Is there a way to prevent that splitting behavior, and simply not show the default settings, but only *my* settings?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```json
"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": false,
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I have vscode 1.78.0. But what worked was adding:  "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": false,

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally set either of the following two settings to `true` (their default values are both `false`):

```json
// Controls whether to use the split JSON editor when editing settings as JSON.
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,

// Controls whether opening settings also opens an editor showing all default settings.
"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
```

You can either find and remove those lines (so they fall back to their default value of `false`, or explicitly set them to `false`).

Side-note: There's also a similar setting for editing keyboard shortcuts: `workbench.settings.openDefaultKeybindings`.